# Difference between .Net3.5 and .Net4.0 regarding WebPermission

Tags: .net, wpf, security, permissions, xbap

We developed an xbap application (**partial trust**) 4 years ago on top of .Net3.5 framework. Last year we upgraded to .Net4.0 for the new release so we are now supporting these 2 versions.

For one of our latest developments we used *WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy* Property which force the usage of WebPermission in our security settings. For the .Net4.0 application we didn't encounter any specific problem, but for the .Net3.5 we started to get "Trust Not Granted" error when we tried to launch the application. We tried sign the manifest and xbap using a certificate but it didn't do the trick (and in .Net4.0 we didn't have this problem at all).

Can anyone shed light on the source for the difference between these two .Net versions?

Thanks,
Ziv

Answer (score 0):

The only *apparent* difference I could find is from the [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.defaultwebproxy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

"The DefaultWebProxy property reads proxy settings from the app.config file. If there is no config file, the current user's Internet Explorer (IE) proxy settings are used."